# How i can get the "Signature" under the IOS Mail, Contacts ,Calendars in my application

Tags: email, ios7

I have a custom ui for sending out email from my IOS app and would like get attach the signature which is configured by the user under Mail, Contacts, Calendars settings. Is it possible to get the signature html and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this information is not available using public API. This is mainly for privacy concerns. If you want to use the user's signature, you should use `MFMailComposeViewController`. If you wish to present your own UI, you need to give an option to the user to set a custom signature for your application.